# Best efficient way to output a list of subsequences and the reverse in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am trying to code a method to output a list of subsequences and the reverse counterparts in Groovy.

This is my current code:

```
LinkedHashSet subsequencesAndReversedOfList(List l, Integer max = null) {
    def output = ( max == null ) ? l.subsequences() : l.subsequences().findAll { it.size() == max }
    def reversedOutput = []
    output.each { reversedOutput << it.reverse() }
    output += reversedOutput
    output
}
```

For an input such as:

```
def l = ['Raisin','Fruit','Apple','Pommes','Nut','Walnut']
Integer max = 2

l = subsequencesAndReversedOfList(l, max)

println l
println l.size()
```

it outputs:

```
Raisin Fruit
Raisin Nut
Raisin Apple
Apple Walnut
Apple Pommes
Raisin Walnut
Fruit Walnut
Fruit Apple
Raisin Pommes
Fruit Nut
Nut Walnut
Pommes Walnut
Pommes Nut
Fruit Pommes
Apple Nut
Fruit Raisin
Nut Raisin
Apple Raisin
Walnut Apple
Pommes Apple
Walnut Raisin
Walnut Fruit
Apple Fruit
Pommes Raisin
Nut Fruit
Walnut Nut
Walnut Pommes
Nut Pommes
Pommes Fruit
Nut Apple
```

It is the output which I am looking for. Is this the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
LinkedHashSet subsequencesAndReversedOfList(List list, Integer max = null) {
    list.subsequences().findAll { max == null || it.size() == max }
        .with {
            it + it*.reverse()
        }
}
```

Which is more efficient in the sense that you have to spend less of your time typing...

What do you mean by "more efficient"?

Comment: I like the elegance of your solution. By "more efficient" I meant which is faster to compute.

Answer (score 1):

In a large list this operation is costly to discard most of the elements = O(n³)

```
l.subsequences().findAll { it.size() == max }
```

You should not use `subsequences()`. You can build a O(n²) implementation

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your solution, you should replace the *O(n³)* complexity expression:

```
l.subsequences().findAll { it.size() == max }
```

The following *O(n²)* computation targets the desired combination size and computes only what is needed:

```
def comb
comb = { m, list ->
    def n = list.size()
    m == 0
        ? [[]]
        : (0..(n-m)).inject([]) { newlist, k ->
            newlist += comb(m-1, list[(k+1)..<n]).collect { [list[k]] + it }
        }
}
```

So the final solution would look something like this:

```
def subsequencesAndReversedOfList = { list, max ->
    (
        max == null
            ? list.subsequences()
            : comb(max, list)
    ).with {
        max == 1
            ? it 
            : it + it*.reverse()
    }
}
```

This implementation does have significant overhead though, so it doesn't really compete with the Groovy `List.subsequences()` based implementation with subsequent filtering until two conditions occur (in varying degrees):

- The number of items in the final result is small (this happens only if `max` is very small or if `max` is close to the size of the base list).
- The size of the base list is large.

In my benchmarking, my targeted solution was always slower than your original filtering solution **until** the list size reached `11`. At that point, the targeted solution was faster for `max` values of `1`, `2`, `3`, `10`, and `11`, the "edge" values. However, by the time the list size reached `20` the targeted solution was measurably faster for all `max` values except `10` and `11`, the middlemost values.